# Next.js+redux+react - Header components is updated before Body component and it looks wierd

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I'm struggling with a very strange behavior.

This is my `Private` page:

```
const Private = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!props.isAuthenticated) {
            Router.push('/login');
        }
    }, [props.isAuthenticated]);

    return (<Layout />);
};
```

The `Layout` component contains an `Header` component that renders also depending on `props.isAuthenticated` (has an `if` statement in the `render()` method).

I'm using redux-saga, so when the user logout from the system, a `LOGOUT_SUCCESS` action is being dispatched and the reducer sets `props.isAuthenticated` to `false`.

Till now everything fine, **BUT**, when this happening, what I see is that:

1) First the `Header` component is updating its display

2) After (let's say **2 seconds**), I see the `/login` body.

This is very strange, when the user need to see an updated header but still with the previous body.

My guess is that the Header is updated before the `Router.push` (because `props.isAuthenticated` was changed) that takes time because it needs to render the `/login` page.

Am i right?
How can i fix it?
What is the best practice such that the whole page will change in once?

Maybe another good question to ask here, is where should the redirect happen? in the end of the saga? (`yield call(Router.push, '/login')`) or in the page useEffect authentication check?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The logout saga:

```
function* logoutFlow() {
    try {
        const res = yield call(sendLogoutRequest);
        yield put({ type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

export function* watchLogoutRequest() {
    yield takeLatest(LOGOUT_REQUEST, logoutFlow)
}
```

The Header component:

```
const Header = (props) => {
    if(props.isAuthenticated){
         return <Button1 />;
    } else {
         return <Button2 />;
    }
}
```

The login/logout reducer:

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGOUT_REQUEST, LOGOUT_SUCCESS } from './loginTypes';

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  loading: false,
  error: ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: true,
        error: ''
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
        error: ''
      };
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error
      };
    case LOGOUT_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you show us the sagas?

Comment: sure, i'm updating the question

Comment: Can you show me also the `Header` component?

Comment: The Header is just rendering Button1 if authenticated and Button2 if not. Not something sophisticated. Semms related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901695/react-redux-how-to-prevent-page-from-rendering-before-redirect but without good solution. I have an idea how to solve it: add to redux state a boolean "redirect" flag. Every time before redirect im turning this flag on, and in the header component i will add in componentWillUpdate a check for the redirect flag. I will update it only if redirect is false. What do you say?

Comment: I will need that Header to see whats going on there

Comment: I don't know how it can help but i added the super simple Header component's code to my post.

Comment: Provide me also the reducer responsible for `LOGOUT_REQUEST` action

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: Do me a favour and add to `case LOGOUT_REQUEST:` - `isAuthenticated: true`

Comment: Can you explain why? when logout request is send isAuthenticated is already true... you agree with me about what the problem is? what do you think about my solution with the redirect state?